# Instascan: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following:

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i am deploying my website to my server, but when i run it, the script for instascan.js is not working, i am having an error of

```
Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src https:".
```

i am using codeigniter as my framework, there's really nothing wrong in my code, because in my localhost, it works just fine, only when i deploy it on the server. is anyone has encountered this problem, how can i resolve this :( i been stuck in this and i can't find any solution on how to fix this problem.

i am using this library

```
https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js
```

Comment: It means your Content-Security-Policy is set up (possibly by default from your hosting service or by codeigniter) to disallow `eval()` of script source.

Comment: @Janessa the source code of the instascan library uses `eval()`, which takes a string and evaluates it as a javascript program. this behavior can be blocked by `Content-Security-Policy` headers from the webserver, and in your case that is what is happening. if you have control of your webserver, you can edit your CSP config to allow eval, and your script will work. if you don't, you will have to find a different library.

Comment: @r3wt why don't you write your comment as an answer?

Comment: thank you, this is a big help. i will follow your advice.

Comment: @Vickel I was just explaining what Pointy said a bit, i don't feel like my comments are fitting for an answer.

Comment: @r3wt I think it would be valuable as an answer, as it for sure helps new developers to understand the issue. As a comment, it is not searchable and might disappear...